# Where can I find Paz?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes

More specifically what building is she in? Or what general direction is the area she's in?

> I've listened to the tape that Chico gives me and I know I'm close but then I lose the telltale sounds of the area she is in.

Answer (score 4):

Paz is being held in the basement of the Administrative building.

To get there, you can either climb into a supply truck and wait for it to "pass through the gates", or you can take one of two doors, one of which can be bypassed using the sewers.

If you have trouble locating the Administrative building, try interrogating a guard or two; one of them is bound to tell you.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a picture of where she is on the map (I/my cursor is standing right in front of her prison cell).  You can sort of see the route to take into the building from the cursor trail.

[image]